# Simple rotating solid Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I am trying to find the volume of the solid that is the region bounded by $y=x^2+1,y=0,x=0,x=1$ rotated about the $x$-axis by the disc method.

What I'm struggling with is the radius. It seems to me that the radius should just be 1 since the vertical shape never gets any skinnier.
$$A(y) = 1\pi\ dx$$
And my limits would be 2 to 0 (max value). Just wondering if this is the right direction.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing $x$ with $y$ here.  First, since the disks are perpendicular to the $x$-axis, the area function should depend on $x$ not $y$.
The radius of each disk is the distance from the $x$-axis (which is $y=0$) up to the curve $y=x^2+1$.  So the radius is $x^2+1 - 0$.  So write instead

$$A(x) = \pi (x^2+1)^2 \; dx.$$

Finally, your limits are in the $x$ direction, not the $y$-direction, so they're given to you in the problem statement.  $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$.